# Translate labels in FormType

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.8

How can I translate labels values in Form builder.

Example:

```
->add('google_analytics_key', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Analytics Key'
            ])
```

the "Analytics Key" is the value for the default locale.

I am using the form with rows:

```
{{ form_row(myForm.google_analytics_key) }}
```

This renders the label with input type as well, so I cannot use the `trans` command.

Is there something built in Symfony/Twig or I must implement the form manually?

Comment: Does it not get translated automatically (look in the profiler)? Also, you can [specify it extra when using `form_row`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-row-view-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the domain of your translation and the key

For example:

```
->add('google_analytics_key', TextType::class, [
    'translation_domain' => '<your file name>',//for example 'messages'
    'label' => 'app.analytics_key',
            ])
```

Comment: what about the default value?

Comment: if the default is en so you need to implement it as well

Answer (score 1):

This is for yml configuration.

First Check:

## app/config/config.yml

framework:
    translator: { fallbacks: [en] }

Then Inside translations folder:
add your transalation file and add:::

## messages.en.yml

test: Analytics Key

## and last just add the reference:

```
->add('google_analytics_key', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'test'
        ])
```