# How to autorewrite input labels for the form in Ttwig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I use almost standard CRUD form rendering in Twig:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr' : {'class' : 'new_edit_form'}}) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
<input type="submit" value="{{ 'default.new.create'|trans }}"/>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

In this case all inputs have labels with upper case property names:

```
Title 
Description
Date
```

I have translations enabled in my project and Twig tries to translate these words, but in my dictionaries all properties have ids like **field.property_name**.
So I want to go through all form inputs and rewrite all labels making them lower case and adding **'field.'** prefix. How can I do this in cycle?

Symfony 3.4

Comment: not sure what framework you are using, but generally , we have this function:  __($field.property_name), which will return you a translated text if there is one, else use your default language

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Translate labels in FormType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173571/translate-labels-in-formtype)

Answer (score 0):

In order to overwrite the translations you need to add the `messages.en.yml` to the `app/YourBundle/Resources/translations` and overwrite the messages you want like:
`field.property_name: Your label here`

This can help: [How to translate labels in symfony2 forms with messages.en.yml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236605/how-to-translate-labels-in-symfony2-forms-with-messages-en-yml)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a specific label for each field:

```
$builder->add('save', TextType::class, array(
    'label' => 'field.sth'
))
```